# Ansible playbook won't match the inventory host file

Tags: linux, ansible

Appreciate if someone could help to find-out why ansible play book not get parent inventory list as i mentioned in site.yml.
provide below message when i executing it.

> > [DEPRECATION WARNING]: The TRANSFORM_INVALID_GROUP_CHARS settings is set to allow bad characters in group names by default, this  will
> >     change, but still be user configurable on deprecation. This feature
> >     will be removed in version 2.10. Deprecation warnings can be disabled
> >     by setting deprecation_warnings=False in ansible.cfg. [WARNING]:
> >     Invalid characters were found in group names but not replaced, use
> >     -vvvv to see details
>
> [WARNING]:  * Failed to parse
>   /home/devopstest/Ansible_Execution/ansible/verification_setup/hosts
>   with yaml plugin: Syntax Error while loading YAML.   did not find
>   expected   The error appears to be in
>   '/home/devopstest/Ansible_Execution/ansible/verification_setup/hosts':
>   line 6, column 1, but may be elsewhere in the file depending on the
>   exact syntax problem.  The offending line appears to be:  [PDC-MGM01]
>   172.25.70.181 ^ here
>
> [WARNING]:  * Failed to parse
>   /home/devopstest/Ansible_Execution/ansible/verification_setup/hosts
>   with ini plugin:
>   /home/devopstest/Ansible_Execution/ansible/verification_setup/hosts:42:
>   Expected group name, got: PDC-NORA0[1:2]
>
> [WARNING]: Unable to parse
>   /home/devopstest/Ansible_Execution/ansible/verification_setup/hosts as
>   an inventory source
>
> [WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is
>   available
>
> [WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available.
>   Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'
>
> /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/**init**.py:91:
>   RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.23) or chardet (2.2.1) doesn't
>   match a supported version!   RequestsDependencyWarning) [WARNING]:
>   Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: environment
>
> PLAY [Configuring Database]
>   ***************************************************************************************************** skipping: no hosts matched
>
> PLAY RECAP
>
> ---

host file

```
#[database]
#172.25.43.180


[PDC-MGM01]
172.25.70.181

[PDC-MGMT02]
172.25.70.181

[PDC-NORA01]
172.25.70.181

[PDC-NORA02]
172.25.70.181

[PDC-ONLN01]
172.25.70.160

[PDC-ONLN02]
172.25.70.184

[PDC-NORA99]
172.25.70.181

[SDC-NORA01]
172.25.70.181

[SDC-NORA02]
172.25.70.181

[SDC-ONLN01]
172.25.70.160

[SDC-ONLN02]
172.25.70.184

[SDC-NORA99]
172.25.70.181

[NORA:children]
PDC-NORA0[1:2]
SDC-NORA0[1:2]
PDC-NORA99
SDC-NORA99

[ONL:children]
PDC-ONLN0[1:2]
SDC-ONLN0[1:2]

[PDC:children]
PDC-MGM0[1:2]
PDC-NORA0[1:2]
PDC-ONLN0[1:2]
PDC-NORA99


[SDC:children]
SDC-NORA0[1:2]
SDC-ONLN0[1:2]
SDC-NORA99

[environment:children]
PDC
SDC
```

site.yml file

```
- name: Configuring Database
  hosts: environment
  remote_user: "{{ env_user }}"
  roles:
    - database-configure
```

Answer (score 0):

1. you should read and fix the warnings
2. the output from the playbook run is unreadable, you should format it properly (just like the yml file)(that's a -1 from me for the question)
3. group names should not contain minus signs (`-`)
4. as you see the ini file parser is choking on `PDC-NORA0[1:2]`. What do you expect should the value of that expression be? Can you leave out all the `[1:2]` and just write `PDC-NORA0` or similar everywhere? Does it work then?